# TAL attribute - if attribute variable is nothing then put "this" instead

Tags: template-engine, zope

I am having a hard time with an optional tal attribute.

```xml
<tal:block define="y_width options/youtube_width | nothing;">

  <div width="437" tal:attributes="width y_width | string:600;"></div>

</tal:block>
```

I want to keep it so that if the user doesn't enter any options in the width value it will default to 437. I thought I could change the "or nothing" operator in the define block but that doesn't work. Above is another thing I tried out putting the or after the attribute but in either case the code justs go away. How can I make it so that if the user input values are empty, the code defaults to certain values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a python expression here, as the `|` pipe operator only kicks in on `AttributeError` or `KeyError`, but in your case "y_width" will be `None`:

```xml
<tal:block define="y_width options/youtube_width | nothing;">

  <div width="437" tal:attributes="width python:y_width or 600;" ></div>

</tal:block>
```